# GDI+ create new SolidBrush globally

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, gdi+, brush

Is there a way to create a **`SolidBrush`** globally, or I have to clone an existing brush?

**Global variable:**

```
Gdiplus::Brush* WhiteBrush;
```

**Scope code:**

```
{
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush white(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 0));
    WhiteBrush = white.Clone();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can new up a brush in the global declaration. It will be constructed during the runtime static object initialization.

```
#include <memory>    
std::unique_ptr<Brush> WhiteBrush( new SolidBrush(Color(255, 255, 255, 255)) );
```

The non-smart pointer version would be:

```
Brush * WhiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color(255,255,255,255));
```